# How to use sensitive passwords needed to run scripts within RunDeck?

Tags: rundeck

I have a case where the RunDeck scripts do need some credentials in order to run. Obviously we do not want to store these in the job definitions because these are visible and also stored in SCM.

While I was able to use the Key Storage vault to put these secrets in, I was not able to find a way to access them from the job itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rundeck 2.6.2 (released 2015-12-02) allows you to specify key storage secrets as default values for secure job options. See [Secure Options using Key Storage](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#secure-options-using-key-storage)

Comment: https://rundeck.org/docs/manual/defining-job-options.html#secure-options-using-key-storage